# how can I open index.html in main activity in Xamarin forms app cross platform application?

Tags: forms, xamarin

i create cross platform application using visual studio 2019  Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) i want to change open main activity to my index.html not to default activity 
were should i change ?
i have folder name assets/index.html

Comment: you need to create a page containing a webview that will open index.html

Comment: yes ... the code and were add this page ? I'm not professional :)

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAlAjouri Xamarin has samples and complete guides for WebView : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to load local html in your contentpage, I suggest you can use **DependencyService** to get html url from Android Assets file, I create simple in android that you can take a look.

Firstly, creating html in Android--Assets file, name as TestWebPage.html.

Then Creating Interface in Form, IBaseUrl.

```
public interface IBaseUrl
{
    string GetUrl();
}
```

Then implementing  this interface in Android platform:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LocalFiles))]
namespace htmlApp.Droid
{
public class LocalFiles : IBaseUrl
{
    public string GetUrl()
    {
        return "file:///android_asset/";
    }
}
}
```

Adding one WebView in ContentPage.

```
 <StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <WebView
        x:Name="webviewjava"
        HeightRequest="300"
        WidthRequest="300" />
</StackLayout>

 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource();

        string baseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().GetUrl();
        string filePathUrl = Path.Combine(baseUrl, "TestWebPage.html");
        urlSource.Url = filePathUrl;
        webviewjava.Source = urlSource;
    }
```

Here is my sample at GitHub, you can download to test it.

https://github.com/CherryBu/htmlapp

Comment: Thank You Cherry for help :) i need a little help , how can I contact you ?

Comment: @Mohammad Ahmad Al Ajouri, Can you describe what problem you encountered, I will see and then help you as much as possible。

Comment: Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)

I have project create in visual studio 2019 Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) cross platform , what i need .. 
i want when the user start the application ( android and IOS ) start my index.html and 
rendering between my html file . the file want to view already include  in Project withe name HTML File ,
 can you please but this files in the Project ? attached find the Project and html file  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mmyW9jphGpqdk532CMCGaAv1hHbnDfVz

Comment: @Mohammad Ahmad Al Ajouri, Do you try my sample? I download you project, but I find it is blank project, please download my sample to test at first:https://github.com/CherryBu/htmlapp

Comment: can you add my www file in your project ? when start your project the main activity my index.html ,,, is that possible:) ?

Comment: My goal  is android and IOS application  .. can add my www already send to you in your project github.com/CherryBu/htmlapp  ?to use android and IOS ?

Comment: @Mohammad Ahmad Al Ajouri, I can see you www folder, but I don't find any html file in this folder, I download the index file, and I find it is also not html file, so I am confused, want do you want to do? You just want to opem html file in MainActivity.cs, not ContentPage?